# Restore open windows after restart/shutdown on Scientific Linux?

Tags: gnome, session, scientific-linux

Is there a way in Scientific Linux to restore all open applications upon the last restart/shut down?

Answer (score 0):

Scientific Linux is based on CentOS, so by default it uses GNOME as desktop environment.

This said, you might use [Window Session Manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1323/window-session-manager/), a Gnome Shell extension that allows you to save the windows of open applications and their size/position to reload them later.